# My version of Red-Black Tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Here's the code I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
    text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
    minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {1}
    child{ node [arn_r] {2} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {4} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {6}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {7}}    
                                              }
    child{ node [arn_r] {3} edge from parent node[above left]
                         {$x$}
            }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to write something beside each arrow... I tried using `edge from parent node[above left]{$x$}`

But it messes up the whole thing, probably cause I'm inserting it in the wrong location.

Plus, I wanna write something beside each circle.. Is there a way to do that too?

Help please!

Comment: Hi Selena. A tip: to mark a whole document as code, don't use the backticks, but select the code and hit CTRL+K or CMD+K. Backticks are usually used for inline code. `:)`

Comment: Providing a screenshot (output of your code) is also expected to make your question self-contained and ease us to digest your question quicker.

Comment: @Ohmyghost Would you please advise me as to how I can do that?

Comment: The simplest approach is: (1) Press "PrintScreen" button, (2) Paste it to an image editor, for example, "Microsoft Paintbrush", (3) Trim the unnecessary part, (4) Save it, (5) Upload it by pressing `CTRL+G`, (6) Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `forest` version just because:

[image: forest tree in black and red]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{%
    /forest,
    forest node/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, text centered},
    arn n/.append style={text=white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black, text width=1.5em},
    arn r/.append style={text=red, draw=red, text width=1.5em, very thick},
  }
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={%
      font=\sffamily,
      forest node,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path[color=black, -stealth', \forestoption{edge}]
          (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      l sep+=.25cm,
      s sep+=.25cm,
    }
    [1, arn n
      [2, arn r
        [4, arn n
          [6, arn r]
          [7, arn r]
        ]
        [3, arn r, edge label={node[midway, right]{$x$}}, label={right:A}
          [8, arn n]
          [9, arn n]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Would this be one possible way to write label beside each node. Use (your current node, for example, for demonstration of the skill. This skill can put text beside the circle too.)

```
 node[above right = 0.8em and -0.5em]{$x$} % or simply `above=0.8 em` will do.
 node[right = 1em]{$A$}
```

On second thought, this may be what you expect.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,positioning}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
    text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
    minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {1}
    child{ node [arn_r] {2} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {4} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {6}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {7}}    
                                              }
    child{ node [arn_r,] {3} node[above right= 2em and -2em]{$x$} node[right = 1em]{$A$}}
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,positioning}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=0pt, text centered,
    font=\sffamily},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, circle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black,
    fill=black, text width=1.5em},% arbre rouge noir, noeud noir
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, circle, red, draw=red, 
    text width=1.5em, very thick},% arbre rouge noir, noeud rouge
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
    minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}% arbre rouge noir, nil
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1.5cm}] 
\node [arn_n] {1}
    child{ node [arn_r] {2} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {4} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {6}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {7}}    
                                              }
    child{ node [arn_r,] {3} node[above right = 0.8em and -0.5em]{$x$} node[right = 1em]{$A$}}
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The code and images look good. But I'm really confused by your introduction to your answer. I honestly don't understand what you mean. Also, I don't know what 'this' refers to when you say 'On the other hand, this may be what you expect.' [I'm assuming you meant 'may be' rather than 'maybe'.]

Comment: OK, the x on the bottom image was put near the arrow tip when I first posted it. But later on, I thought the x should be moved a little bit higher than the first image and then I posted the top image again. Yes, I meant `may be`. Thanks.

Comment: But what does 'This skill can text' mean? Do you maybe mean 'demonstrate the technique' and 'This technique can also be used to place text beside the circle'? [Note that I mean this to be a helpful suggestion. If you would prefer I go away, just say so. ;)]

Comment: Oh, No No..., I appreciate your comments, @cfr, it improves my writing ;-).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind compiling with `lualatex` then you could try the graph drawing stuff that comes with `PGF 3.0` (NB. I don't think this is a valid red-black tree):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta,quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]

\graph [tree layout,
  nodes={shape=circle, ultra thick, font=\sffamily, Sentinel},
  Red/.style={shape=circle, text=red,   fill=white, draw=red},
  Black/.style={shape=circle, text=white, fill=black, draw=black},
  Sentinel/.style={shape=rectangle, fill=black}]{

 1[Black] -> 2[Red] -> { 
   4[Black] -> {
     6[Red, >"$a$", label=180:$b$] -> {/,/}, 
     7[Red] -> {/,/}
   },
   3[Red, >"$x$", label=0:$y$] -> {/,/}
 };

};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]